# Why my useState is not updating the value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an useState that gets the value from DB:

```js
const [checklist, setChecklist] = useState(undefined);
```

[image]

And I have this condition, that when happens, I would like to change the useState:

```js
let newItems = [];
let newChecklist = {};

  if (project?.analysisData?.actionPlan == "no") {
    newItems = checklist?.items?.filter(
      (item) => item.conformityStatus !== "initial_status"
    );
    newChecklist = { ...checklist, items: newItems };
  }
```

Notice that the items were filtered.

[image]

And I'm trying to change the value from my useState with useEffect:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setChecklist(newChecklist);
  }, []);
```

But for some reason it's not changing.. Anyone can help me?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Having a component-level variable for this is probably a bad idea.  Why use `newChecklist` at all?  Just call `setChecklist({ ...checklist, items: newItems });` inside the `if` block.

Comment: I think your if condition is false. you are checking checklist variable with && operator when its undefined. i think that will return false.

Comment: The useEffect is in a state that is will only run once after mount you have to make that dependant so that I some condition or value cchanges useEffect runs and updates the satet

Answer (score 1):

I created a new useState:

```js
const [changeChecklist, setChangeChecklist] = useState(true);
```

called a setTimeout, to force some "change" after the component Mount:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    setChangeChecklist(false);
  }, 550);
```

and called the useEffect with the change of my new useState:

```js
let newItems = [];

  useEffect(() => {
    if (project?.analysisData?.actionPlan == "no") {
      newItems = checklist?.items?.filter(
        (item) => item.conformityStatus !== "initial_status"
      );
      setChecklist({ ...checklist, items: newItems });
    }
  }, [changeChecklist]);
```

Maybe its not the best solution, but it was the one that I figured out to solve my problem :)